# Disabling self pull request merge on github

Tags: github, pull-request

In Github, is it possible to disable the option for users to open pull requests and merge them by themselves?

So that every pull request HAS to be approved by another user.

Answer (score 1):

I believe protected branches offer this.

1. Go to the repository settings.
2. Go to "branches"
3. Choose the target branch you want to protect.
4. Check "Protect this branch", then require reviews. You can also include repository administrators.

[image]